# How do you implement an onFling event in TouchImageView so it acts like the galleries you see in Facebook or Google+

Tags: android, multi-touch, onfling

There are a handful of questions out there, but none really provided a clear solution to this problem.  Android does not have anything built in to do so, so Mike Ortiz implemented [TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java) which is awesome.  It works perfectly for what it is supposed to do.  But now I want to turn this into a Gallery that uses the onFling gesture to scroll in another TouchImageView.  What is the best way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

I forked [MikeOrtiz's TouchImageView](https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView) to add ViewPager compatible capability. Check it out here: [Forked TouchImageView](https://github.com/hank-cp/TouchImageView)

Comment: @Hank: I use TouchImageView too (highy recommended!!), that I also tweaked to avoid longclicks. I took a look at your code, and failed to find a fling gesture. I know that you can scroll when the image is zoomed. But is there a way to use fling, say, to go to the next image (when image is not zoomed) with your code? Thanks!!

Comment: @LuisA.Florit, did you checkout README.md? It contains an example that works with ViewPager. ViewPager will do the fling things for you.

Comment: @Hank: oh,  I see. So it is not TouchImageView that implements fling, as I understood. Got it now. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

I wanted the same functionality and I found out ViewPager is the best solution of all.
http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

Here is the sample code which may work for you,

[Set default page for ViewPager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395655/563306)

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but I think I'll run into the same issue as I did with putting ImageTouchView in a gallery, the gallery overrides the touch events causing you not to be able to zoom in and out.