# Can't find android.support support package

Tags: android, eclipse

I made a folder called libs to my working space.

I copied the android-support-v4.jar in it.

Pressed right on it  Build Path > Add to Build Path.

Next i added a library and there it needs the Viewpager.

Afterwards i cleaned my project, but  i cann't access android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.

Eclipse don't find android.support as well

Solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the library to your build path after you copy the file in the libs directory.

Once you copy the file in libs directory, right click on project, build path, libraries and select the libs directory of the project and add it.

You can then import the classes.

Comment: It says ViewPager works with Android 1.6 or more... however, I had problems with 1.6 It works only for 2.1 or more versions.

Comment: I think the problem is with the component you want to add, which uses ViewPager. You may try this code and see if it works. http://stackoverflow.com/q/7395655/563306

Comment: i deleted the refernced library, but i cannot find the ViewPager

Comment: If you delete the library in libs directory and copy again, you will need to do that in build path-> libraries too. Remove the library in build path and try adding jar file again(after you copy the jar file in libs directory).