# setContentView doesn't allow search to work

Tags: java, android, android-intent

I have been tryng to get my search function working ever since adopting TabHosts and I have figured out that in my `onCreate` method for my Search class that when `setContentView(R.layout.main);` it causes the following error

```
03-30 09:19:53.301: E/AndroidRuntime(728): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4053c270 is not valid; is your activity running?
```

When I comment it out though the search dialog pops up when you click on the hardware search button and I can type a value and press search but then I get the next stumbling block

```
03-30 09:23:37.061: D/PhoneWindow(776): couldn't save which view has focus because the focused view com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4053ff38 has no id.
```

Below is my code as it is at the moment for my Search class

```
public class Search extends ListActivity {

private TextView mTextView;
//protected ListAdapter adapter;
private DxDbAdapter mDbHelper;
DxSimpleCursorAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    //mTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text1);

    // Get the intent, verify the action and get the query
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {
      String query = intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
      doMySearch(query);
    }
}

public void doMySearch(String query_results) {
    //SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();

    mDbHelper = new DxDbAdapter(this);
    mDbHelper.open();

    String[] columns = new String[] {"diagnosis", "diagcode"};
    int[] to = new int[] {R.id.diagnosis, R.id.code};

    //  Add "No Results Found" message 

    Cursor cursor = mDbHelper.search(query_results.trim());
    //Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select _id, diagnosis, diagcode From DiagLookup Where diagnosis Like ? order by diagnosis asc", new String[]{"%"+query_results.trim()+"%"});

/*      if (cursor == null) {
        mTextView.setText(getString(R.string.no_results, new Object[] {query_results}));
    }
    else {*/ 
        adapter = new DxSimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_detail,cursor,columns,to);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
 //     }
}

public void onListItemClick(ListView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = (new DatabaseHelper(this)).getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor c = (Cursor) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    String arg = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("_id"));
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("Select category, subcategory From DiagLookup Where _id = ?",  new String[]{""+arg});
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Category: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("category")) + "\nSubcategory: " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("subcategory"));
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
}
```

Furthermore I created a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` so I can do some actions to an imageview. When I originally had entered `adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_detail,cursor,columns,to);` entering a search term and pressing on the search button had populated the listview but my imageview was not functioning so when I just changed the code to `adapter = new DxSimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.list_detail,cursor,columns,to);` and added on the top `DxSimpleCursorAdapter adapter;` it no longer worked and caused the couldn't save focus error.

I am using `TabActivity` and `ActivityGroup` to create tabs along the top of my app and I think my context is messed up which is causing the focus to be lost...I am not sure though.

Anyone with some guidance on how I can go about solving these issues?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

1. If you are using TabActivity, why use the ListActivity again? If you want to use the ListView inside the Tabs, you can simply define it in the layout xml file.
2. If you want to use the Tabs inside an activity, then try this out, [Android: TabHost without TabActivity](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3163884/563306)
3. Switch to ViewPager instead of TabActivity [Set default page for ViewPager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7395655/563306)

Comment: to provide more context to the implementation of the TabActivity etc I followed the example outlined [here](http://ericharlow.blogspot.ca/2010/09/experience-multiple-android-activities.html)