# How To Set Default Layout in Android

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I have a two layouts that scroll back and forth in an Activity. When I press the home button, it returns to the first layout. What I want to do is set the "home" layout to be the second layout i.e. when i press the home button I want it to return to the second screen and not the first. I am having trouble doing this, if anyone could help me I would be very grateful. I didn't include the XML files they have nothing important.

### Launcher.java

```
public class Launcher extends FragmentActivity {

    ViewPager viewpager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_launcher)

        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewpager.setAdapter(adapter);

    }
}
```

### PagerAdapter.java

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        switch (arg0) {
            case 0:

                return new Fragment1();

            case 1:

                return new Fragment2();

            default:
                break;
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }

}
```

### Fragment1.java

```
public class Fragment1 extends Fragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_apps,container,false);
    }

}
```

### Fragment2.java

```
public class Fragment2 extends Fragment {

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_homescreen,container,false);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using PagerAdapter then use this line to set your default layout`mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);` this will set your 2nd layout as default, layout number starts from 0,1,2,... 
Hope this thing help you out.

Comment: Thank you! This is actually so simple!

Answer (score 0):

In this link [Set default page for ViewPager in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7395655/set-default-page-for-viewpager-in-android), i feel it is the same problem. Maybe it can help you.